# VS CODE - Code Runner - Output not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

When I run code on VS Studio Code, instead getting an output in the "Output" I get the output in "Terminal".

I used to get it under "Output" before. I am using Code Runner as extension.

Answer (score 0):

The Code Runner extension runs code in the Output tab by default.

[image: Run in output]

However, you can set Code Runner to run in the Terminal tab by going to the Settings (Press `Ctrl + ,`) and then tick the `Code-runner: Run in Terminal` option:

[image: Settings]

After ticking this box, Code Runner now runs code inside the Terminal tab:

[image: Run in terminal]

Did you accidentally tick the `Code-runner: Run In Terminal` option? If so, untick that option so that Code Runner runs code inside the Output tab.